# read y or n to confirm deletion unix shell

Tags: shell, unix

I have trying to have a unix shell script ask the user whether they want to delete an item.

I have the following code

I keep getting the following error
./menu.sh 73: [: missing ]

```
echo "Confirm deletion: (y)es or (n)o: "
read confirmDeletion

if [ "$confirmDeletion"="y"];
then
    echo "YES"  
else
    echo "NO"
    pause
fi
```

I cannot seem to work out what is wrong
Any help will be appreciated
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need spaces around the `=` operator:

```
if [ "$conformDeletion" = "y" ];
```

and before the ]